# Why is the output false for the same value of 2 different hashmaps?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, comparison

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> 
    map1 = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>(),
    map2 = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();
    HashSet<Integer> set1=new HashSet<Integer>();
    set1.add(1);
    set1.add(2);
    map1.put(1,set1);
    map2.put(1,set1);
    System.out.println(map1.values()==map2.values());
    System.out.println(map1.values()+" "+map2.values());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the references of two `Collection<HashSet<Integer>>>` objects but you want to compare two `<HashSet<Integer>>` objects. Try extracting `<HashSet<Integer>>` objects from `Collection<HashSet<Integer>>>` objects and compare them with `equals()` method. By the way - result of comparing the references with `==` should also be `true`.

Comment: Or in this case, *call* the equals method.

Answer (score 1):

The correct comparing the equality of Object data types is to use the method `equals()`.

```
map1.equals(map2);
```

Comment: He wants to compare two hashSet objects. System.out.println(map1.values().equals(map2.values())); also prints false.

Answer (score 1):

`==` tells you whether two values are the same. *However*, the value of `map1.values()` is *not* a collection containing the set, but rather a reference to a collection containing a reference to the set.

Because they are references, `map1.values() == map2.values()` tells you whether `map1.values()` and `map2.values()` refer to the same object, which they do not, so it evaluates to false.

You can compare two objects by calling the `equals` method, such as with `map1.values().equals(map2.values())`.

Answer (score 0):

Both map1 and map2 create their own lists of `values`. Both lists have one single element in your case, and that is the same `==`. If you would have used `equals` then both lists would have been equal. `==` tests for object equality/identity.

By the way, the convention in java is:

```
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
```

For using interfaces (Map, Set) for the variables there is reason: as such one might change the implementation, for instance to a TreeMap where the keys are sorted. Especially nice: your code will function  with the broadest variation of  types.